# Does the 3.4.2 Dashboard have Chrome Frame headers?

Tags: dashboard, google-chrome

A quick google search for "Wordpress Dashboard Chrome Frame" seems to indicate that 3.2 and up integrate Google Chrome Frame is included in the Dashboard, but I haven't been able to find anything official from Wordpress about it, and when I inspect the headers in Chrome, I don't see the standard Chrome Frame headers. Anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 2):

From `wp-includes/vars.php`:

```
if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) {
    if ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Lynx') !== false ) {
        $is_lynx = true;
    } elseif ( stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'chrome') !== false ) {
        if ( stripos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'chromeframe' ) !== false ) {
            if ( $is_chrome = apply_filters( 'use_google_chrome_frame', is_admin() ) )
                header( 'X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1' );
            $is_winIE = ! $is_chrome;
        } else {
            $is_chrome = true;
        }
```

In plain English: If a user agent header is set, and there is the string `chrome` in it and the string `chromeframe` too – read: it is an Internet Explorer with Chrome Frame installed – and it is an request to `wp-admin` … then send `X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1`.

> […] when I inspect the headers in Chrome, I don't see the standard Chrome Frame headers.

Of course you don’t. Chrome Frame is an [extension for Internet Explorer](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/), not for the Chrome browser. :)

Comment: In theory, I see why this should work. Detect if Chrome Frame is installed, and if so, send the header with the command to use it. However, Chrome Frame wasn't activating in IE for me until I added a plugin to Wordpress (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/chrome-frame/) It works fine with the plugin, but I thought it was supposed to work out of the box without a plugin?